# Freeradius TLS cetificate(win 7 and previous)

Tags: windows, windows-7, certificate, tls, freeradius

I'm configuring FreeRADIUS 2.2.6. I use TLS because TTLS is not supported by windows 7.

- With Windows 8.1 the WiFi connection works very well without installing certificate
- With Windows 7 and previous the connection doesn't work without certificate

I need to make it easy to connect for the user. Is it possible for users to authenticate without the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

No the primary use case for EAP-TLS it to perform mutual authentication using certificates. Both the supplicant and server must provide a certificate.

If you want to use password based authentication, EAP-PEAPv0 has been available on the Windows platform since Windows 2000 SP4. For that to work, you'll need the NT-Password or Cleartext password of the user stored in a directory or database.

Comment: thanks for the reply . I set PEAPv0 / EAP - MSCHAPv2 , but I still have problems certificate.

Comment: You don't make it clear which certificate you're having problems with, the client certificate or the server certificate?

Comment: client................

Comment: ....... What you're saying doesn't make sense, you can't use client certificates with PEAPv0, so you can't still have issues with a client certificate.

Comment: i use PEAPv0 with EAP-MSCHAPv2